# How do you get the background image of UICollectionViewCell to aspectFit to the cell on rotation?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios-autolayout

I have a collectionview with a custom cell.
[image]

How do I get the image to fill the collectionviewcell on roatation?
init code in collectioncell:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: contentView.frame)
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "images")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = false
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)


    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    let guide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    //title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    //title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
}
```

[image]

Comment: this seems to work when i set it as backgroundview:          backgroundView = imageView

Answer (score 0):

```
  collectionView.invalidateLayout()
```